# What does it mean to 'attach a cone along a subspace'?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, terminology, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

I am a little bit confused about the terminology used in Section 2.4 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.08196.pdf). We have a finite pointed CW complex $B$ and a subcomplex $A$. Then "let $C$ be obtained from $B$ by attaching a cone $I\wedge A$ along the subspace $\{1\}\times A=A$". **What does this mean explicitly?**

I am familiar with mapping cylinders/cones in topology, defined as quotients of a disjoint union and assume it relates to this in some way but it seems unclear.

Comment: Do you understand the meaning of the word "attach"? How about the meaning of "cone"?

Comment: @MoisheKohan In everyday usage, yes. But I can't make sense of what the quoted part means explicitly in terms of quotient spaces or whatever is intended

Comment: I mean the meaning of the word "attach" and "cone" when used in topology. This is not the same as the everyday meaning, say, in industry.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Does it relate to this by any chance? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjunction_space   I'm far more comfortable with this sort of thing expressed in terms of quotient spaces/pushouts etc. and I guess I'm not too familiar with the meanings in topology

Comment: Of course. This slang is ubiquitous in the topology literature.

Comment: I'd like to know what attach and cone mean in industry (rhetorical)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be the (standard) mapping cone of the inclusion $A\rightarrow B$. Sections 44 and 45 of the excellent Algebraic Topology notes by Haynes Miller (easy to find online; I am unsure how to attach link as you did) may help. Also fits into adjunction space as pointed out above by @moishekahan. Comments above only appeared as I finished this.